# Single-value-tuple as last member of struct in swift

Tags: swift, core-audio, coremidi

`MusicPlayer`'s API relies on variable length arrays as the last member of a struct to handle passing around data of unknown size. Looking at the generated interface for `MusicPlayer`, the structs used in this method present their last element in a single value tuple.

example:

```
struct MusicEventUserData {
    var length: UInt32
    var data: (UInt8)
}
```

I doubt that any of this has been officially exposed but has anyone figured out whether this syntax is a red herring or actually significant? I don't think that there is a means to hand arbitrarily sized things via swift but does this help when calling from C?

Comment: Here is a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724055/initializing-midimetaevent-structure with a possible solution (or workaround). I do hope that this will become easier in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MusicPlayer is no longer exported as above. As of Xcode 6.3b1

```
typedef struct MusicEventUserData
{
    UInt32      length;
    UInt8       data[1];
} MusicEventUserData;
```

This is much closer to the C declaration. It still does not completely explain how to deal with the API in swift but that is another question.

Answer (score 1):

after test on a playground I can see there is no difference between (Int) and Int type.
Here is my tests :

```
func testMethod(param1: Int, param2: (Int)) -> Int{
    return param1 + param2
}

testMethod(2, 3) // return 5
testMethod(3, (6)) // return 9
```

About the calling in C, I just think it is a little bug on the bridging from ObjC to swift

Comment: I understand that. The question was about the fact that the single element notation lined up with a  C idiom. There weren't any other examples of Apple generating types with that syntax and it always lined up with the variable length structs.